# How do UI systems find the specific object for a mouse event

Tags: user-interface

When you recieve window click or mouse move events from the OS (or something like GLFW), you are only provided with X & Y position of the mouse.
While if you use a UI system like Qt, you recieve events for the specific widget/element that the mouse is over.

I have been wondering what happens in between, how do UI systems determine which UI object the mouse is currently over? Are there any specific algorithms that do such search efficiently?

I have tried to google this question first, but all results I get are about subscribing to mouse events in specific UI systems or game engines.

Comment: "how do UI systems determine which UI object the mouse is currently over?" - by examining the z-order of UI elements at a given coordinate.

Comment: "Are there any specific algorithms that do such search efficiently?" - you don't need anything fancy: you can iterate over every control's/widget/child's rectangle back-to-front to test for collision in `O(n)` time (if controls are pre-sorted in z-order).

Comment: @Dai well yes, of course you can just do a O(n) search, i've just been wondering if there are maybe any approaches to do it more efficiently :)

Answer (score 0):

You could store the bounds of an element and all its neighbours, and then check which of its neighbours the mouse is over when it leaves the bounds. These neighbours could also be just empty rectangles with their own bounds and neighbours. This would only work for rectangle-based UI's.

It would be harder to calculate neighbours for un-aligned elements but still possible:
[example of misaligned element neighbours](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ibYuK.png)

Comment: (pretend all the things in the image are rectangles)